# Express - can't retrieve username and password from request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing system for login and registration. When I post correct details in my register Post method, my request is pending and I am unable to find error. The one error it is giving `data and salt arguments required` and I am getting status 500 and pending my fetch method in ejs file is producing error "Error: data and salt arguments required"

```
const users = [];
let status = "";

router
  .route("/register")
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.render('register', {message: ''})
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    console.log([req.body.password, req.body.email]);
    const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
    const checkUser = {
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
    };
    const { value, error } = validateUser(checkUser);
    if (error) {
      status = "error"
      res.status(404).render('register', {message : error.message});
    } else {
      const user = users.find((u)=>{
        if(u.email === req.body.email){
          status = "user exist"
          res.status(404).render('register',{ message : "user exist"})
        }else{
          const newUser = {
            email : req.body.email,
            password: hashPassword
          }
          users.push(newUser)
          console.log("users is" + users)
          res.status(200).render('ok')
        }
      })
    }

  });
```

the errors i am getting in console

```
[ undefined, undefined ]
Error: data and salt arguments required
    at Object.hashSync (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodejs\login\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:91:15)
    at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodejs\login\routes\login.js:24:33
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodejs\login\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodejs\login\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at next (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodejs\login\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodejs\login\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodejs\login\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodejs\login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodejs\login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\nodejs\login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
[ '113245', 'sambhav@gmail.com' ]
```

this is the frontend system i am using

```
  <body>
    <h1>register</h1>
    <p><%=message%></p>
    <form action="/api/register" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="enter email" /><br />
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        id="password"
        placeholder="enter password"
      /><br />
      <button type="submit">register</button>
      
    </form>
    <a href="/api/login">login</a>
    <script>
      const form = document.querySelector('form')
      const email = document.querySelector('#email')
      const password = document.querySelector('#password')
      form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch("/api/register", {

          // Adding method type 
          method: "POST",

          // Adding body or contents to send 
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email.value,
            password: password.value,
          }),

        })

          // Converting to JSON 
          .then(response => response.json())

          // Displaying results to console 
          .then(json => console.log(json));
      })
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: May you share what line of the code is throwing the error? Is it `bcrypt.hashSync`?

Comment: i think so because salt is related with bcrupt @evolutionxbox

Comment: @tdashby87 What does req.body.password return, is it undefined perhaps? If so make sure to allow json through your body parser. You can do this by using: app.use(express.json());

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#to-hash-a-password-1 seems to say that a salt needs to be passed. I'm not sure `10` can be salt 

Comment: actually my req.body.password and req.body.email is showing undefined

Comment: Can you put complete backend code? I need to check how is your express server created and what middleware it uses.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote useful answers and accept ones that solve your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Values `req.body.password` and `req.body.email` are clearly undefined, so `bcrypt.hashSync` is complaining that it cannot hash a null/undefined value.

It looks like the values are not being POSTed correctly. Check your code to make sure you are using body-parsing middleware (e.g. `router.route("/register").use(bodyParser.json())`).
You should also look at your frontend code or in devtools for a clue as to why they are not being passed.

I can't tell if your request is hanging, but additionally, you may want to define an [error handling route](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) in Express if you do not want the requests to hang when there is a server error (if you have not already).

Remember also that any sync function on a server will block incoming requests until it completes

Comment: i have added front end also as i am unable to resolve error

Comment: @tdashby87 Can't see the issue - have you used Devtools to confirm that the user & password are sent in the request?

Comment: @tdashby87 any luck?